# Evolution ews connection to exchange suddenly stopped working (unauthorized)

Tags: 15.10, email, 16.04, evolution

I was using Evolution with the EWS (Exchange Webservices) Connector for quite a while and everything was working well.

Then from one day to the next, without any configuration change I know of, I started getting "unauthorized".

I tried to reset all the Evolution configuration (after backing up my local email) using the following command.

```
rm -rf .cache/ .local/share/keyrings/ .local/share/evolution/ .config/evolution/
```

I also deleted the system keyring as you can see.

After rebooting the system and re-configuring evolution, I still get "unauthorized" again.

Here is the output of `EWS_DEBUG=2 evolution`

```
> POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
> Soup-Debug-Timestamp: 1461566380
> Soup-Debug: SoupSessionAsync 1 (0x55c06aef6be0), ESoapMessage 1 (0x55c06d87f910), SoupSocket 1 (0x7fbe08005dc0)
> Host: example.example.local
> User-Agent: Evolution/3.18.5
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
> Authorization: NTLM AUTH-DATA-REDACTED-FOR-STACKOVERFLOW
> 
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SOAP-ENV:Header><types:RequestServerVersion xmlns:types="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:messages="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"><messages:SyncFolderHierarchy xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><messages:FolderShape><BaseShape>AllProperties</BaseShape></messages:FolderShape></messages:SyncFolderHierarchy></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Soup-Debug-Timestamp: 1461566380
< Soup-Debug: ESoapMessage 1 (0x55c06d87f910)
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
< WWW-Authenticate: NTLM AUTH-DATA-REDACTED-FOR-STACKOVERFLOW
< WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="example.example.local"
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Mon, 25 Apr 2016 06:39:42 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
```

I was using Ubuntu 15.10 when it stopped working. In the meantime I upgraded to 16.04, hoping this would solve the problem, which didn't.

Also I tried my account on a colleague's computer in Evolution EWS and it works. On my computer it is not even working when logging in with another system user (and thus clean configuration).

- How can I solve this problem?
- Are there any other caches or temporary storages that can be removed?
- Any idea how to further debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes due to update of some samba libraries, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution-mapi/+bug/1571854?comments=all
Unfortunately I am also affected :-(

Comment: I was able to solve it with `sudo apt-get remove winbind` - thank you so much, I was struggling for days with that.